# Primefaces SummaryRow render header columns title

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Unfortunately I have problem with PrimeFaces SummaryRow.

What I need to do is create a simple SummaryRow with some content. But always when I put something into SummaryRow renderer of PrimeFaces Datatable add extra string from column header.

Below some code:

```
 <p:dataTable var="orderProductVariantSerializable" 
                     reflow="true" 
                     sortBy="#{orderProductVariantSerializable.serialVersionUID}"
                     value="#{cartView.orderSerializableList}">


            <p:column class="image-column" headerText="#{stringProduct}">
                <c:set var="productVariant" value="#{orderProductVariantSerializable.productVariant}" />
                <ui:include src="../parts/product_image.xhtml" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column  headerText="#{stringDescription}">
                <p:outputPanel class="cart-cell-wrapper cart-description">
                    <h:outputText class="cart-description-manufacturer"
                                  value="#{orderProductVariantSerializable.productName.product.manufacturer.aname}"/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{orderProductVariantSerializable.productName.avalue}"/>
                </p:outputPanel>
                <p:outputPanel class="cart-cell-wrapper attributes-column">
                    <p:dataList
                        var="position"
                        rendered="#{not empty orderProductVariantSerializable.variantItemList}"
                        value="#{orderProductVariantSerializable.variantItemList}">
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                            <h:outputText value="#{position.attributesNames.avalue}"/>
                            <p:dataList var="attributesPositionsName" value="#{position.attributesPositionsNamesList}">
                                <h:outputText value="#{attributesPositionsName.avalue}"/>
                            </p:dataList>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:dataList>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </p:column>

            <p:column class="quantity-column" headerText="#{stringQuantity}">
                <p:outputPanel class="cart-cell-wrapper">
                    <h:panelGrid class="quantity-table">
                        <p:outputPanel>
                            <p:inputNumber decimalPlaces="0" readonly="true" value="#{orderProductVariantSerializable.amount}"/>
                        </p:outputPanel>
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                            <p:commandLink rendered="#{cartView.shouldRenderEnabledMinus(orderProductVariantSerializable)}"
                                           actionListener="#{cartView.decrementQuantity(orderProductVariantSerializable)}" process="@form"
                                           onstart="NProgress.start();" 
                                           oncomplete="NProgress.done();">
                                <i class="fas fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </p:commandLink>
                            <p:commandLink rendered="#{cartView.shouldRenderDisabledMinus(orderProductVariantSerializable)}" disabled="true">
                                <i class="fas fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </p:commandLink>
                            <p:commandLink actionListener="#{cartView.incrementQuantity(orderProductVariantSerializable)}" process="@form"
                                           onstart="NProgress.start();" 
                                           oncomplete="NProgress.done();">
                                <i class="fas fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </p:commandLink>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="#{stringAvailability}">
                <h:outputText value="#{orderProductVariantSerializable.productVariant.amount}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column class="unit-price-column" headerText="#{stringUnitPrice}">
                <h:outputText value="#{orderProductVariantSerializable.finalPriceGross}">
                    <f:convertNumber groupingUsed="true" minFractionDigits="2"/>
                </h:outputText>
                <h:outputText value="#{layoutView.currency.aname.toUpperCase()}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="#{stringToPay}">
                <h:outputText value="#{orderProductVariantSerializable.toPayAll}">
                    <f:convertNumber groupingUsed="true" minFractionDigits="2"/>
                </h:outputText>
                <h:outputText value="#{layoutView.currency.aname.toUpperCase()}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="#{stringToPay}">
                <h:outputText value="#{orderProductVariantSerializable.toPayAllNet}">
                    <f:convertNumber groupingUsed="true" minFractionDigits="2"/>
                </h:outputText>
                <h:outputText value="#{layoutView.currency.aname.toUpperCase()}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column class="delete-column">
                <p:commandLink actionListener="#{cartView.deleteProductFromCart(orderProductVariantSerializable)}" 
                               class="cart-trash"
                               update="#{cartView.formId}"
                               onstart="NProgress.start();" 
                               oncomplete="NProgress.done();">
                    <i class="fas fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </p:commandLink>
            </p:column>

            <p:summaryRow>
                <p:column colspan="8" >
                    <h:outputText value="Summary:" />
                </p:column>
            </p:summaryRow>

        </p:dataTable>
```

Like u can see in SummaryRow I have just outputText with value 'Summary:'. But renderer of datatable add extra text from first Column headerText which is 'Produkt'. Finally I get in html (summary-row) something like 'ProduktSummary:'

and image (result):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Guyz. I found solution. I hope that will help someone with the problem. The solution it just remove **reflow** attribute from datatable and it will be working well =).

I hope the post will be helpful for someone

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try removing `colspan = 8` on column of summaryRow.

Answer (score 0):

Like I promise in comment I will put my fix.

This error happen also with me, my colleague helped me to solve it with disable some css, so in your style you can add for :

for **p:headerRow** :

```
<p:headerRow>
   <!-- some code -->
</p:headerRow>
```

you can disable that problem using :

```
.ui-rowgroup-header > td .ui-column-title {
    display: none;
}
```

---

for **p:summaryRow**

```
<p:summaryRow>
   <!-- some code -->
</p:summaryRow>
```

you can disable that problem using :

```
.ui-datatable-summaryrow > td .ui-column-title{
    display: none;
}
```

---

Or both of them just combine them like this :

```
.ui-rowgroup-header > td .ui-column-title, .ui-datatable-summaryrow > td .ui-column-title{
    display: none;
}
```